# Stop Link href when certain condition is met in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have large no of files on my website and I'm trying to put download limit for every user.
download link looks like that.

```
   <a class="btn btn-primary" id="download" href="<?php echo $content_url;?>" onclick=”var that=this;_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’,’Download’,’PDF’,this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;” target="_blank">
     <i id = "<?php echo $id; ?> " class="fa fa-download">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Download
   </a>
```

Onclick Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#download").click(function(event){
$.ajax({
  url      : '/ajax/download-file.php',
  dataType : 'json',
  aysnc : false,
  success : function(response)
  {
    if (response.error_type == 'login') 
    {
      $("#login_modal").modal('show');
    }
    else
    {
      var login_id = "<?php 
      if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']))
      {
        echo $_SESSION['login_id'];
      }
      ?>";
      console.log(login_id);
      $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/ajax/track_downloads.php',
        data : {login_id : login_id},
        async : false,
        success : function(response)
        {
          var download_link = $("#download").attr("href");
          if(response == 1)
          {
            return false;
            alert("Your Download Limit Has Been Exceeded");
          }
        }
      });
      }
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
```

My code is working fine and it checks for download limit allotted to each user,if it's less than 20 pdf get open in next tab but, if limit crosses 20 alert box should get displayed and stop the link from proceeding forward.

So Main Question is : I want to stop link when response == 1,I've tried event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault and .remove already but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

stop link mean's if your `track_downloads.php` code return 1 then you can remove your link by just calling `.remove();` method of jquery. this is best solution you cant use disable or display:none that's not safe.